# Test class code coverage when test class is taking long time to run

Tags: apex

I have a test class for a batch apex. When deploying to production, I am getting a 69% code coverage. So I am a few short of the 75%. The problem is when I run the test class it is taking hours/days to execute this. I am not sure how to make this test class or even the class better so that it takes quicker to run and more importantly gets over 75% coverage. Also, is there a way to check code coverage/lines covered without running the test class?

This is the main batch apex:

```
/* This class is used to update the contracts' pricebooks for renewals and amendments.
 */
global class UpdateContractPB_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> { 
        
    global Iterable<SObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        id CurrPB = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND Current_Price_Book__c = TRUE LIMIT 1].Id;
        System.debug('Current Pricebook: ' + CurrPB);
        
        IF(test.isRunningTest()){
            return [SELECT ID, SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c , SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c FROM Contract WHERE (Status = 'Activated' OR Status = 'Draft') AND RecordTypeID = '0120c000001ZWXKAA4' AND SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c = FALSE AND (SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c !=:CurrPB OR SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c !=:CurrPB) LIMIT 1];
        }else{
            return [SELECT ID, SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c , SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c FROM Contract WHERE (Status = 'Activated' OR Status = 'Draft') AND RecordTypeID = '0120c000001ZWXKAA4' AND SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c = FALSE AND (SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c !=:CurrPB OR SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c !=:CurrPB)];
        }
        
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contract> updateContractPBs) {    
        // process each batch of records
        id CurrPB2 = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND Current_Price_Book__c = TRUE LIMIT 1].Id;
        System.debug('Current Pricebook: ' + CurrPB2);
        
        for (Contract ucp:updateContractPBs){UpdateContractPricebookUtil.ProcessUpdateContractPricebook(ucp,CurrPB2);}
    
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // execute any post-processing operations
  }
  global static void run()
  {
    UpdateContractPB_Batch batchjob = new UpdateContractPB_Batch();
    Integer BatchSize = 10;
    Database.executeBatch(batchjob,BatchSize);
  }
}
```

here is the utility class:

```
public class UpdateContractPricebookUtil  {

public static void ProcessUpdateContractPricebook(Contract updateContractPB, id CurrentPB)
{
          updateContractPB.SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c = CurrentPB;
          updateContractPB.SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c = CurrentPB;
          
        try {
            // Update the Contract Record
            update updateContractPB;
        
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug(e);
        }
         
    }
   
 }
```

here is the scheduler class:

```
//declaration of scheduler class

global class UpdateContractPBSched implements schedulable

{

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    UpdateContractPB_Batch.run();
  }

}
```

here is the test class for the batch apex which is at 69%:

```
@isTest 
public class UpdateContractPB_Batch_t {

  @IsTest
  static void test_UpdateContractPB_Batch() {
  
  Id userId = '0050c00000Du0Rz';
        User user1 = [select id from user where id = :userId];
        System.runAs(user1) {  
        
        fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c exrg = new fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c(CurrencyISOCode = 'USD', fferpcore__DefaultCurrency__c = 'USD - U.S. Dollar', Name = 'FF Shared Test Group', fferpcore__SelectedCurrencies__c = 'USD - U.S. Dollar');
        insert exrg;
        c2g__codaCompany__c company = new c2g__codaCompany__c();
        company.Name = 'ApexTestCompany';
        company.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.c2g__codaCompany__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('SUT').RecordTypeId;
        insert company;
        company.c2g__ExchangeRateGroup__c = exrg.Id;
        update company;
        c2g__codaAccountingCurrency__c curr = new c2g__codaAccountingCurrency__c(c2g__OwnerCompany__c  = company.Id, Name = 'USD', CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD', c2g__Home__c = TRUE, c2g__UnitOfWork__c = 1, c2g__DecimalPlaces__c = 2);
        c2g__codaUserCompany__c usercmpy = new c2g__codaUserCompany__c(c2g__Company__c = company.Id, c2g__User__c = userId);
        
        List<fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c> LsExchRateGroup = [Select Id, Name From fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c Where Name like 'FF Shared %' Order By CreatedDate DESC limit 1]; 
        Id ExGroup = LsExchRateGroup[0].Id;
        
        Id caseOnboardingRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Onboarding').getRecordTypeId();
        
        Product2 prodObj = new Product2(
                 Name = 'Test Product'
                ,ProductCode = 'abc' 
                ,isActive = TRUE
                ,SBQQ__QuantityEditable__c = TRUE
                ,SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c = 'Fixed Price'
                ,SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c = 12
                ,SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c = 'Renewable');
        insert prodObj;
        
        PricebookEntry strPrBkEntryObj = new PricebookEntry(
                       pricebook2Id = '01s300000009t4nAAA'
                      ,product2id  = prodObj.Id
                      ,unitprice = 2000
                      ,isactive  = TRUE);
        insert strPrBkEntryObj;   
        
        PricebookEntry PrBkEntryObj = new PricebookEntry(
                       pricebook2Id = '01s0c0000003vFfAAI'
                      ,product2id  = prodObj.Id
                      ,unitprice = 2000
                      ,isactive  = TRUE);
        insert PrBkEntryObj;
        
        Account a = new Account(RecordTypeId = '012300000002yUcAAI', Support_Level__c='Basic', Type = 'Customer', Name = 'Contract Test Account', Region__c = 'NAM', Ownership = 'Private', Website = 'https://www.financialforce.com', CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD', Preferred_Currency__c = 'USD', NumberOfEmployees = 100, FF_Customer_Success_Manager__c = userId, SFDC_Edition__c = 'Enterprise Edition');
        insert a;
        
        Case caseObj = new Case();
                caseObj.accountId = a.Id;
                caseObj.status = 'Unassigned';
                caseObj.type = 'Onboarding';
                caseObj.recordTypeId = caseOnboardingRecordTypeId;
                caseObj.priority = 'Medium';
                caseObj.contactId = '0034Q000036PKwqQAG';
              
         insert caseObj;
        
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(RecordTypeId = '01230000000YdHSAA0', AccountId = a.id, Type = 'Renewal', Name = 'Test Renewal', CloseDate = date.today(), StageName = '01 - (Renewal) Opportunity Assessment', CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD', inCurrencyRate__c = 1, Probability = 85, Welcome_Email_Contact__c = '0034Q000036PKwqQAG', Onboarding_Contact__c = '0034Q000036PKwqQAG');
        insert o;
        
        SBQQ__Quote__c q = new SBQQ__Quote__c(RecordTypeId = '0120c000001ZWXcAAO', SBQQ__Type__c = 'Quote', SBQQ__PriceBook__c = '01s0c0000003vFfAAI', SBQQ__PricebookId__c = '01s0c0000003vFfAAI', SBQQ__StartDate__c = date.today(), SBQQ__EndDate__c = date.today() + 365, SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c = 12);
        insert q;
        
        SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(SBQQ__Quote__c  = q.Id, SBQQ__Product__c = prodObj.Id);
        insert ql;

        SBQQ__QuoteLineGroup__c g = new SBQQ__QuoteLineGroup__c(SBQQ__Quote__c = q.id);
        insert g;
    
        Contract c = new Contract(RecordTypeId = '0120c000001ZWXKAA4', SBQQ__Opportunity__c = o.id, AccountId = a.id, SBQQ__Quote__c = q.id, Status = 'Draft', StartDate = date.today(), ContractTerm = 12);
        insert c;
        
        SBQQ__Subscription__c s = new SBQQ__Subscription__c(SBQQ__Contract__c = c.id, SBQQ__Account__c = a.id, SBQQ__SubscriptionStartDate__c = date.today(), SBQQ__SubscriptionEndDate__c = date.today() + 365, SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c = 'Renewable', SBQQ__CustomerPrice__c = 2000, SBQQ__ListPrice__c = 2000, SBQQ__NetPrice__c = 2000, SBQQ__Number__c = 1, Paid_Months__c = 12, SBQQ__Product__c = prodObj.Id, SBQQ__PricingMethod__c = 'List', SBQQ__ProductSubscriptionType__c = 'Renewable', SBQQ__ProrateMultiplier__c = 1, SBQQ__Quantity__c = 1, Renewable_Subscription_Checkbox__c = TRUE, SBQQ__SpecialPrice__c = 2000, SBQQ__QuoteLine__c = ql.Id);
        insert s;
        
        Pricebook2 p = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Test Price Book', IsActive = TRUE, Current_Price_Book__c = TRUE);
        insert p;
        
        System.debug('Current Pricebook: ' + p.Id);
        system.assertNotEquals(c.SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c, p.Id);
        system.assertNotEquals(c.SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c, p.Id);
        
        test.startTest();
        
        List <Pricebook2> p1 = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND Current_Price_Book__c = TRUE LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('Current Pricebook: ' + p1.size());
        system.assertEquals(TRUE, p1.size() > 0);
        
        List <Contract> c1 = [SELECT ID, SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c , SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c FROM Contract WHERE (Status = 'Activated' OR Status = 'Draft') AND RecordTypeID = '0120c000001ZWXKAA4' AND SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c = FALSE AND (SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c !=:p1[0].id AND SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c !=:p1[0].id) LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('New Contract: ' + c1.size());
        system.assertEquals(TRUE, c1.size() > 0);
        
        UpdateContractPB_Batch batchjob = new UpdateContractPB_Batch();
        Database.executeBatch(batchjob,1);
        
        //UpdateContractPB_Batch.run();
        
        UpdateContractPricebookUtil.ProcessUpdateContractPricebook(c,p.id);
        
        List <Contract> c2 = [SELECT ID, SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c , SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c FROM Contract WHERE (Status = 'Activated' OR Status = 'Draft') AND RecordTypeID = '0120c000001ZWXKAA4' AND SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c = FALSE AND (SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c =:p1[0].id AND SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c =:p1[0].id) LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('New Contract: ' + c2.size());
        system.assertEquals(TRUE, c2.size() > 0);
        
        system.assertEquals(c2[0].SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c, p1[0].Id);
        system.assertEquals(c2[0].SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c, p1[0].Id);
        
        test.stopTest();
        
        }
        
    }
}
```

Can someone please let me know what changes i can make to increase it to over 75%?

would the modified test class look like this?

```
@isTest 
public class UpdateContractPB_Batch_t {

  @IsTest
  static void test_UpdateContractPB_Batch() {
  
  Id userId = '0050c00000Du0Rz';
        User user1 = [select id from user where id = :userId];
        System.runAs(user1) {  
        
        fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c exrg = new fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c(CurrencyISOCode = 'USD', fferpcore__DefaultCurrency__c = 'USD - U.S. Dollar', Name = 'FF Shared Test Group', fferpcore__SelectedCurrencies__c = 'USD - U.S. Dollar');
        insert exrg;
        c2g__codaCompany__c company = new c2g__codaCompany__c();
        company.Name = 'ApexTestCompany';
        company.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.c2g__codaCompany__c.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('SUT').RecordTypeId;
        insert company;
        company.c2g__ExchangeRateGroup__c = exrg.Id;
        update company;
        c2g__codaAccountingCurrency__c curr = new c2g__codaAccountingCurrency__c(c2g__OwnerCompany__c  = company.Id, Name = 'USD', CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD', c2g__Home__c = TRUE, c2g__UnitOfWork__c = 1, c2g__DecimalPlaces__c = 2);
        c2g__codaUserCompany__c usercmpy = new c2g__codaUserCompany__c(c2g__Company__c = company.Id, c2g__User__c = userId);
        
        List<fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c> LsExchRateGroup = [Select Id, Name From fferpcore__ExchangeRateGroup__c Where Name like 'FF Shared %' Order By CreatedDate DESC limit 1]; 
        Id ExGroup = LsExchRateGroup[0].Id;
        
        Id caseOnboardingRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Onboarding').getRecordTypeId();
        
        Product2 prodObj = new Product2(
                 Name = 'Test Product'
                ,ProductCode = 'abc' 
                ,isActive = TRUE
                ,SBQQ__QuantityEditable__c = TRUE
                ,SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c = 'Fixed Price'
                ,SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c = 12
                ,SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c = 'Renewable');
        insert prodObj;
        
        PricebookEntry strPrBkEntryObj = new PricebookEntry(
                       pricebook2Id = '01s300000009t4nAAA'
                      ,product2id  = prodObj.Id
                      ,unitprice = 2000
                      ,isactive  = TRUE);
        insert strPrBkEntryObj;   
        
        PricebookEntry PrBkEntryObj = new PricebookEntry(
                       pricebook2Id = '01s0c0000003vFfAAI'
                      ,product2id  = prodObj.Id
                      ,unitprice = 2000
                      ,isactive  = TRUE);
        insert PrBkEntryObj;
        
        Account a = new Account(RecordTypeId = '012300000002yUcAAI', Support_Level__c='Basic', Type = 'Customer', Name = 'Contract Test Account', Region__c = 'NAM', Ownership = 'Private', Website = 'https://www.financialforce.com', CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD', Preferred_Currency__c = 'USD', NumberOfEmployees = 100, FF_Customer_Success_Manager__c = userId, SFDC_Edition__c = 'Enterprise Edition');
        insert a;
        
        Case caseObj = new Case();
                caseObj.accountId = a.Id;
                caseObj.status = 'Unassigned';
                caseObj.type = 'Onboarding';
                caseObj.recordTypeId = caseOnboardingRecordTypeId;
                caseObj.priority = 'Medium';
                caseObj.contactId = '0034Q000036PKwqQAG';
              
         insert caseObj;
        
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(RecordTypeId = '01230000000YdHSAA0', AccountId = a.id, Type = 'Renewal', Name = 'Test Renewal', CloseDate = date.today(), StageName = '01 - (Renewal) Opportunity Assessment', CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD', inCurrencyRate__c = 1, Probability = 85, Welcome_Email_Contact__c = '0034Q000036PKwqQAG', Onboarding_Contact__c = '0034Q000036PKwqQAG');
        insert o;
        
        SBQQ__Quote__c q = new SBQQ__Quote__c(RecordTypeId = '0120c000001ZWXcAAO', SBQQ__Type__c = 'Quote', SBQQ__PriceBook__c = '01s0c0000003vFfAAI', SBQQ__PricebookId__c = '01s0c0000003vFfAAI', SBQQ__StartDate__c = date.today(), SBQQ__EndDate__c = date.today() + 365, SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c = 12);
        insert q;
        
        SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(SBQQ__Quote__c  = q.Id, SBQQ__Product__c = prodObj.Id);
        insert ql;

        SBQQ__QuoteLineGroup__c g = new SBQQ__QuoteLineGroup__c(SBQQ__Quote__c = q.id);
        insert g;
    
        Contract c = new Contract(RecordTypeId = '0120c000001ZWXKAA4', SBQQ__Opportunity__c = o.id, AccountId = a.id, SBQQ__Quote__c = q.id, Status = 'Draft', StartDate = date.today(), ContractTerm = 12);
        insert c;
        
        SBQQ__Subscription__c s = new SBQQ__Subscription__c(SBQQ__Contract__c = c.id, SBQQ__Account__c = a.id, SBQQ__SubscriptionStartDate__c = date.today(), SBQQ__SubscriptionEndDate__c = date.today() + 365, SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c = 'Renewable', SBQQ__CustomerPrice__c = 2000, SBQQ__ListPrice__c = 2000, SBQQ__NetPrice__c = 2000, SBQQ__Number__c = 1, Paid_Months__c = 12, SBQQ__Product__c = prodObj.Id, SBQQ__PricingMethod__c = 'List', SBQQ__ProductSubscriptionType__c = 'Renewable', SBQQ__ProrateMultiplier__c = 1, SBQQ__Quantity__c = 1, Renewable_Subscription_Checkbox__c = TRUE, SBQQ__SpecialPrice__c = 2000, SBQQ__QuoteLine__c = ql.Id);
        insert s;
        
        Pricebook2 p = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Test Price Book', IsActive = TRUE, Current_Price_Book__c = TRUE);
        insert p;
        
        System.debug('Current Pricebook: ' + p.Id);
        system.assertNotEquals(c.SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c, p.Id);
        system.assertNotEquals(c.SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c, p.Id);
        
        
        List <Pricebook2> p1 = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND Current_Price_Book__c = TRUE LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('Current Pricebook: ' + p1.size());
        system.assertEquals(TRUE, p1.size() > 0);
        
        List <Contract> c1 = [SELECT ID, SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c , SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c FROM Contract WHERE (Status = 'Activated' OR Status = 'Draft') AND RecordTypeID = '0120c000001ZWXKAA4' AND SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c = FALSE AND (SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c !=:p1[0].id AND SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c !=:p1[0].id) LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('New Contract: ' + c1.size());
        system.assertEquals(TRUE, c1.size() > 0);
        
        test.startTest();

        //UpdateContractPB_Batch batchjob = new //UpdateContractPB_Batch();
        //Database.executeBatch(batchjob,1);
        
        //UpdateContractPB_Batch.run();
        
        //UpdateContractPricebookUtil.ProcessUpdateContractPricebook(c,p.id);
```

Test.startTest();
System.schedule('TEST PB SCHED', '0 0 * * * ?', new UpdateContractPBSched());
Test.stopTest();

```
        List <Contract> c2 = [SELECT ID, SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c , SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c FROM Contract WHERE (Status = 'Activated' OR Status = 'Draft') AND RecordTypeID = '0120c000001ZWXKAA4' AND SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c = FALSE AND (SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c =:p1[0].id AND SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c =:p1[0].id) LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('New Contract: ' + c2.size());
        system.assertEquals(TRUE, c2.size() > 0);
        
        system.assertEquals(c2[0].SBQQ__RenewalPricebookId__c, p1[0].Id);
        system.assertEquals(c2[0].SBQQ__AmendmentPricebookId__c, p1[0].Id);
        
        
        
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Test.stopTest() before assertions. That said, you could increase your coverage a bit by calling scheduler instead of batch directly:

```
Test.startTest();
System.schedule('TEST PB SCHED', '0 0 * * * ?', new UpdateContractPBSched());
Test.stopTest();
```

Also, consider removing your try-catch block if you are only going to System.debug() the results away. You'll get slightly better coverage.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox, So i just put my new version of the test class above. Is that what the test class should look like? Thank you